# cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null - handsontable.full.js:3714

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

I tried to run the example mentioned in the Quick start link([Quick Start](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/tutorial-quick-start.html)). Downloaded all files via Git hub. when trying to run the example mentioned in quick start getting the following error  "cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null  - handsontable.full.js:3714". Please help me running the basic example.

Version used - v0.16.1

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="dist/handsontable.full.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var data = [
    ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2014", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2015", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2016", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

  var container = document.getElementById('example');
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: data,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            contextMenu: true
          });

</script>
<style>
body {
background-color: white;
margin: 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
</style>
</head>

 <body>


    <h2>Default Handsontable Demo</h2>

     <div id="example"></div>

 </body>
```

Comment: @ZekeDroid's answer helped me in solving it. sorry for late reply.

Comment: This work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624007/javascript-handsontable-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-insertbefore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting your 3 script nodes in your body rather than in the head. It feels like an issue with how you're loading the modules.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and, at least for me, the error happened because I've used an element ID that doesn't exist.

In this line:

```
var container = document.getElementById("example");
```

Make sure that ID of your div has the same name. In this case, it is "example":

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

If container is `undefined` when loading Handsontable, this error message will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

some time even space cause this  error.

```
// example 
var container = document.querySelector('header .container');
//in this i made mistake of space between header and container class so  he can't find and show me error
var container = document.querySelector('header .container');
```