# Javascript Handsontable - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using the handsontable library for creating neat tables.
I literally copied the tutorial but the console (web developer console) gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined            
handsontable.full.js:4471
```

I link both the .css and the .js file correctly in the `<head>` tags.

My javascript looks like this:

```
var data = [
    ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var container = document.getElementById('temp');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    dropdownMenu: true
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="temp"></div>
```

Line 4471 in handsontable.full.js is

```
rootElement.insertBefore(this.container, rootElement.firstChild);
```

The table isn't displayed, the error in the console is all I've got.

Comment: My guess is you are trying to read the element before it exists on the page. Either call the code onload or put the code after the element on the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like that your

```
document.getElementById('temp');
```

return undefined.

Make sure that the container element is still there when `Handsontable` is constructing.

Comment: You were right. I'm loading in my content dynamically and the script was called before the content was loaded therefore the div was nonexistent.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rootElement` reference is undefined. Please check where is this variable defined and to what it is assigned.